# Why there is double\r\n instead of \r\n in the codes

Tags: python, image, data-retrieval

original codes from PY4E:

```
import socket
import time
HOST = 'data.pr4e.org'
PORT = 80
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect((HOST, PORT))
mysock.sendall(b'GET http://data.pr4e.org/cover.jpg HTTP/1.0\n\n')
count = 0
picture = b""

while True:
    data = mysock.recv(5120)
    if (len(data) < 1): break
    time.sleep(0.25)
    count = count + len(data)
    print(len(data), count)
    picture = picture + data
mysock.close()

# Look for the end of the header (2 CRLF)
pos = picture.find(b"\r\n\r\n")
print('Header length', pos)
print(picture[:pos].decode())

# Skip past the header and save the picture data
picture = picture[pos+4:]
fhand = open("stuff.jpg", "wb")
fhand.write(picture)
fhand.close()
```

my questions are little more:

- what is the mean of `picture=b''`
- what is `pos` for?
- What is `[pos+4:]` in`picture=picture[pos+4:]` for?
- How can I view the image? 
  Thanks for any guidance in advance.

Comment: This is just basic HTTP parsing.

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere? If you don't understand it, probably not a good idea to use it

Comment: @ cricket_007, It is from PY4E tutorial, I am figuring out what the codes mean.

Comment: There's a comment in the code that tells you what your title asks. Did you even read that code? (And if the code is from a tutorial, why are you then coming here to ask us to tutor you about the tutorial's code? It seems to me that you should re-read the tutorial that leads up to that code, because you're apparently not following it too well.)

Comment: Your questions reveal a total lack of knowledge of the language. You essentially attempt to read a book in Arabic without knowing the Arabic alphabet. No matter what is your goal, this is a very bad idea.

Comment: I admire I am an idiot. Someone who just wanna criticize plz just leave.  Bullying an idiot just waste your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the mean of `picture=b''`

This is setting the `picture` variable to an empty byte array, which will be added to later.

> what is `pos` for?

In `pos = picture.find(b"\r\n\r\n")`, the code is looking for the end of the HTTP header that comes before the picture data.

> What is `[pos+4:]` in `picture=picture[pos+4:]` for?

The comment above it explains it, it "Skips past the header" to just get the picture data.

> How can I view the image?

In these two lines,

```
fhand = open("stuff.jpg", "wb")
fhand.write(picture)
```

the picture is saved to a file titled `stuff.jpg`, you should be able to double click in a file manager to open it.

Comment: Can I know what is `+4: `in `[pos+4:]`? means?

Comment: The issue is that the stuff.jpg can not open or view. Is there any trouble on this code?

Comment: @ChristopherKnight Yes, there is an error in the tutorial code:  Near the top, it should be:  `mysock.sendall(b'GET http://data.pr4e.org/cover.jpg HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')`.  You should have seen a 'Bad Request' response by the http server, if you ran the original code.

Comment: @robert_x44 `pos = picture.find(b"\r\n\r\n")` is the something be matched with the command you just gave? And can i view the picture on the python by `print()`? or is there any default path for saving image?

Comment: @ChristopherKnight This is just how the http specification is written.  You send a request, with a `\r\n` which ends the line you sent and a second `\r\n` which is a blank line.  On the other end, after the headers are sent, the last header line ends with a `\r\n` and then a `\r\n` which is a blank line.  Searching for the `\r\n\r\n` is an easy way to find a blank line - which indicates that the headers are finished, and the rest is the data you requested.

Comment: @ChristopherKnight You can't view an image with print, open it up with an image viewer program.

Comment: @ robert_x44 thanks for your help. send `xxxxxxx\r\n\r\n` and receive `xxxxxxx\r\n\r\n` is easier than different ending (like `\r\n`)? Any reason the author wants to leave two blank lines instead of one? Would you mind to explain`+4:` in the `[pos+4:]`? You guys really helpful